# python running count of values in dict

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have a dictionary like this

```
d = {1:'Bob', 2:'Joe', 3:'Bob', 4:'Bill', 5:'Bill'}
```

I want to keep a count of how many times each name occurs as a dictionary value. So, the output should be like this:

```
d = {1:['Bob', 1], 2:['Joe',1], 3:['Bob', 2], 4:['Bill',1] , 5:['Bill',2]}
```

Comment: Hint: add the names to a list and use the `count` method.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered and your keys are just ordered integers. You might be happier with a list.

Comment: dict is unordered. Your counting assumes that you expect to have some sort of order in your dict? can you clarify?

Comment: @Marcin, what do you know, python actually sorts the dict that way too :)

Comment: I know they aren't supposed to but I have found that they do keep thier order.

Comment: @user2333196 No they dont, even if they appear so in your example. For this you need to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: @A.J  It sorts them by value of hash function, not by order.

Comment: @Marcin, for his example they actually will (regardless of the size of the size of his map), because the hashcode of an int is just the int itself in python, and python prints the elements in the map in order of ascending (hash(key)% capacity). But the capacity is always higher than the number of elements and the number of elements is the highest hashcode in this example. That's why they're in order. This isn't a mechanic meant to rely on though.

Comment: @Soronbe Even it this is the case for this example (I dont know), in general its better to not to rely on ordering of keys in regular dict. For this there is orderedict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of counting the values like you want, is shown below:

```
from collections import Counter


d = {1:'Bob',2:'Joe',3:'Bob', 4:'Bill', 5:'Bill'}


c = Counter()
new_d = {}

for k in sorted(d.keys()):
    name = d[k]
    c[name] += 1;  
    new_d[k] = [name, c[name]]

print(new_d)  
# {1: ['Bob', 1], 2: ['Joe', 1], 3: ['Bob', 2], 4: ['Bill', 1], 5: ['Bill', 2]}
```

Here I use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to keep track of occurrences of names in the input dictionary. Hope this helps. Maybe not most elegant code, but it works.

Answer (score 6):

To impose an order (which a `dict` per se doesn't have), let's say you're going in **sorted** order on the keys.  Then you could do -- assuming the values are hashable, as in you example...:

```
import collections

def enriched_by_count(somedict):
    countsofar = collections.defaultdict(int)
    result = {}
    for k in sorted(somedict):
        v = somedict[k]
        countsofar[v] += 1
        result[k] = [v, countsofar[v]]
    return result
```

Answer (score 4):

Without using any modules, this is the code I came up with. Maybe not as short, but I am scared of modules.

```
def new_dict(d):
    check = [] #List for checking against
    new_dict = {} #The new dictionary to be returned
    for i in sorted(d.keys()): #Loop through all the dictionary items
        val = d[i] #Store the dictionary item value in a variable just for clarity
        check.append(val) #Add the current item to the array
        new_dict[i] = [d[i], check.count(val)] #See how many of the items there are in the array

    return new_dict
```

Use like so:

```
d = {1:'Bob', 2:'Joe', 3:'Bob', 4:'Bill', 5:'Bill'}
d =  new_dict(d)
print d
```

Output:

```
{1: ['Bob', 1], 2: ['Joe', 1], 3: ['Bob', 2], 4: ['Bill', 1], 5: ['Bill', 2]}
```